# how to find project to contribute as automation tester?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, training

I'm manual QA with 3 years of experience. At the same time I've learnt some automation and wrote autotests on java for selenium-based framework on the previous job. I decided to get more knowledge of automation, chosen YouTrack API to write some API test project, chosen domestic site to write some website test project with Selenium. Now I'm looking for a way to find real-life project to contribute to instead of writing something useless.

What I tried:

1. search on github for something like "qa automation" with label "help wanted": nothing from mature projects, tons of irrelevant items from one-day projects.
2. reading of quora, stackexchange and similar: in fact there were couple of live projects, but not for java automation.
   Also it leads me to different projects from Mozilla, Apache foundation, Selenium. But after diving to their contribution pages I found that opportunities for writing of autotests are obsolete or not explicitly mentioned.

The only abstract option, which I found and consider to be realistic, is to find some open-source project with badly covered API and to propose patch with autotests for it. But still don't know any good particular project for it.

So would be glad to get any help. Especially recommendations of projects for writing of java autotests via WebDriver (or other tool), for API or just unit-tests.

Answer (score 0):

A few points to notice are:

- Most free software are tested by the people who write the production code, and often through TDD. Rarely there are people "writing tests" solely;
- Selenium is not the first choice for most free software projects, because of the first and because it replacement with lighter tools.

Nonetheless, one way of finding projects who use a certain library is to look at GitHub for the string who loads this library in the main dependency management systems. E.g. in Maven you can "selenium-java", which you can look for in GitHub, like  this https://github.com/search?q=%22%3CartifactId%3Eselenium-java%3C%2FartifactId%3E%22&type=code.

However, you want to support a project, I would first look for a project that you understand its usage/context, then see if the technology at least resembles something you are familiar with.
†wo popular choices are the game [0 A.D.](https://play0ad.com/community/participate/) and the office suite [LibreOffice](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/QA).